# UIview kept going at the bottom of the UIViewcontroller

Tags: swift

My LoginViewController has a  UIView that has  2 UItextfield and 1 UIbutton. The moment the user start writting the UIView should go up and leave space for the keyboard. However my problem is when the  keyboard disappear the UIView did not go at its initial position. Can anyone help me please Thank you ... (my code is below)

```
  func keyboardON(sender: NSNotification) {

    let info = sender.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize = info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue().size
    println("keyboard height \(keyboardSize.height)")
    var frame = otherContainerView.frame
    println("MainScreen :\(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)")
    frame.origin.y = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - keyboardSize.height - frame.size.height
    otherContainerView.frame = frame

}

func keyboardNotOn(sender: NSNotification) {
    let info = sender.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize = info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue().size
    println("keyboard height \(keyboardSize.height)")
    var frame = otherContainerView.frame
    frame.origin.y = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height -  frame.size.height
    otherContainerView.frame = frame
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you change this view controller to a UITableViewController with static cells. When using a UITableViewController, the scrolling is automatically handled, thus making your problem not problem at all.

[image: Login page being handled with a UITableViewController.]

If I understand your initial question correctly, you are trying to create a login screen in a UIViewController, which is fine, but much harder than it would be to simply create a UITableViewController. The image above was made with a UITableViewController. When the text fields are selected, it slides up, and when they are deselected, it moves back to it's initial view. If you switch to a UITableViewController, (even if you place both UITextFields and the button in one cell), you won't need to do any of this programmatically. The storyboard will handle the desired changes.

```
import UIKit

class LoginTableViewController: UITableViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField : UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField : UITextField!

   @IBAction func login (sender: UIButton) {
       //login button
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }


   override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 1
   }

   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

       //If you choose to use 3 cells in your storyboard (like I've done with my login screen) you will return 3 here. If you choose to put all of the items in one cell, return 1 below.
       return 3
   }

}
```

Comment: I've updated my response to explain a little more why the method you're trying to implement is harder than it could be.

Comment: In your main.storyboard, you will need to drag out a UITableViewController and make it of type LoginTableViewController. Once you've done that, make sure the cells are static. Add your UITextFields and your UIButton. Then connect your textfields and your button to the IBOutlets found above. That's all you should have to do.

Comment: You will only need to set the cellForRowAtIndexPath if your cells are dynamic. You are going to want them to be static, however.

Comment: Hey Ravi, if you liked the answer I provided, I would appreciate it if you chose it as the accepted answer. Thanks! I'd be happy to help you more if you are still confused as well.